# Testing with Selenium and reCaptcha v3

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, recaptcha

Here is the thing.
I know that bypassing reCaptcha is something complicated and I am not talking about how to do it. Let's say,I want to do the automation but I can manually do the reCaptcha. But I want my script to wait on me when I do that and continue to run after I finish the reCaptcha. Is it possible? If so, please give me some tips of how to do it. Thanks ahead.

Comment: Did you try to use "time.sleep()" function for passing reCaptcha? I am not sure but if you pass reCaptcha manually in that time gap, it can work after that step maybe.

Comment: wait until the element (the captcha) is gone. However I would suggest whatever it is you're doing, your approach is wrong.